# Numpy not found when not in ipython

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

I am trying to run a python script that imports numpy from the command line

```
 python script.py
```

and it throws an importError for numpy.
When I launch ipython and do:

```
 %run script.py
```

it works fine. How do I fix this? I would like to be able to run sutff without having to go into ipython.

OS: CentOS
Error Message: ImportError: No module named numpy

Comment: Please provide full error traceback

Comment: And operating system?

Comment: Is your ipython installation part of enthought or canopy or something similar?

Comment: Show the difference between plain python and ipython for `import sys; print(sys.path)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what was causing the problem -- the machine has several python versions installed and the python executable invoked when calling python was for python 2.6.6 which did not have the numpy module installed.

Running:

```
 python2.7 script.py
```

worked fine.

I am putting this here in case somebody else has this problem. Just invoking python in the shell and looking at the version it says it is cleared up the issue for me. Ipython is configured to use python2.7.6 on my machine.

Comment: It's often helpful to run `which python` or `which ipython` at the shell. That will give you a clue to where it is installed, and often which version you're using.